# Radare2/r2pipe Binary writng mode

Tags: python-2.7, reverse-engineering, elf, radare2

I want to write some data to the ELF binary.  I have tried to use this r2pipe function `r = r2pipe.open('binary', flags=['-w']` 
How can I add some strings to ELF binary by using r2pipe binary write mode function? Sorry for this stupid question. 
Any advice and simple example is appreciated.

````
r2 = r2pipe.open("ncc1", flags=['-w'])
r2.write("HELLO world")
r2.close()```

Result: AttributeError: 'open' object has no attribute 'write'
````

Answer (score 0):

As [many](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2-r2pipe/blob/master/python/examples/batch.py) [examples](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2-r2pipe/blob/master/python/README.md) of using `r2pipe` show, you don't *write* to the pipe.

Instead you use `r2.cmd(...)` to communicate with the underlying `radare2`.